# Kubuntu 14.04 stuck on splash screen

Tags: boot, kubuntu, plymouth

[image: blah]
[image: blah]

I can operate the terminal normally with `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, but `Ctrl+Alt+F7` is stuck on the boot splash screen. I have 2 AMD Radeon 7850 graphics cards and I'm using the proprietary drivers, so maybe this is the issue? I don't know how to change the settings without a desktop UI, however.
How can I get my system to boot to GUI normally?